# Function prints an array but returning null when called php

Tags: php, laravel

I have following function which helps me get category name.

```
public function getParent($categoryId, $keepData) {
    $parentCategory = Category::select('category_id', 'parent_id', 'title')
                               ->where('category_id', $categoryId)->first();

    if($parentCategory->parent_id > 0) {
        $parent = Category::select('category_id','parent_id','title')
                           ->where('category_id',$parentCategory->parent_id)
                           ->first();
        $keepData[$parent->category_id] = $parent->title;
        $this->getParent($parent->category_id, $keepData);
    } else {
        //print_r($keepData);
        return $keepData;
    }
}
```

When I do `print_r` inside function it prints an array.

```
 array:2 [▼
     3 => "Stock Boxes"
     1 => "Boxes"
 ]
```

but calling this function from other function as,

```
$keepData = array();
$breadcrumb = $this->getParent($categoryId, $keepData);
print_r($breadcrumb);
```

then it returns `null`.

What is the step I am missing. any help would be great.

Comment: what is your expected data in the `$keepData` as per your function if `parnet_id = 0`it will `return null;`

Comment: What is the purpose of passing empty `$keepData` to `getParent()` ?

Comment: Try to pass `$keepData` as reference variable in your method, it should return your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this condition

```
if ($parentCategory->parent_id > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

evaluates to `true`, and in this block you are not returning anything, that's why the method invocation effectively returns `null`.

Adjust the method to

```
public function getParent($categoryId, array $keepData = [])
{
    $parentCategory = Category::select('category_id', 'parent_id', 'title')->where('category_id', $categoryId)->first();

    if ($parentCategory->parent_id > 0) {
        $parent = Category::select('category_id','parent_id','title')->where('category_id',$parentCategory->parent_id)->first();
        $keepData[$parent->category_id] = $parent->title;

        return $this->getParent(
            $parent->category_id, 
            $keepData
        );
    } 

    return $keepData;
}
```

and invoke like this (note how `$keepData` is turned into an optional parameter and defaults to an empty array):

```
$breadcrumb = $this->getParent($categoryId);
```

Comment: Thnx...U are a life saver. ..It worked like a charm.